# Pre-selection of features does not work

Tags: openlayers, angular, typescript

We are implementing a tool which allows users to select a so called *Section* on the map and edit its *Segments*. One Section consists of one or more Segments and is always displayed as a single line.

When user selects some section, we extract its ID from the properties and make a call to back-end to obtain Segments belonging to the Section. When we receive them we want to display them as pre-selected features in a Select object. And this doesn't work.

```typescript
// sectionFeatures - array of Segments belonging to the selected Section
private initSegmentSelection(sectionFeatures: Array<Feature<Geometry>>): void {
  this.selectSegmentsInstance = new Select({
    condition: click,
    toggleCondition: () => true,
    style: selectSegmentsStyle,
    hitTolerance: MAP_CONSTANTS.HIT_TOLERANCE,
    filter: (feature) => feature.getProperties()['modelType'] === EntityType.SegmentEntity,
  });

this.selectSegmentsInstance.on('select', (event: SelectEvent) => this.onSegmentsSelected(event));
this.mapService.registerInteraction(this.selectSegmentsInstance);

// This works, but the problem is that the selection style is not applied -> selection is not visible.
this.selectSegmentsInstance?.dispatchEvent({
  type: 'select',
  selected: [test],
  deselected: []
} as any); // TypeScript otherwise throws error on BaseEvent
// If I check the selection afterwards, I'll get back the features but the style is not applied
```

Selection instance is created and it works. User can select various segments on the map, when its active. But I can figure out how to pre-select some segments. Solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422598/openlayers-3-select-a-feature-programmatically) does not work for me.

**Open Layers version - 8.2.0**

**EDIT:**
Edit the code

Comment: `this.selectSegmentsInstance?.getFeatures().push(f)` should be enough, without `dispatchEvent`. If you want to use `dispatchEvent`, then leave out `this.selectSegmentsInstance?.getFeatures().push(f)`, but you have ti use `selected: [f]` option.

Comment: You may need to add the interaction to the map before pushing features.

Comment: It's registered, I just didn't put that line in the question

Comment: @mat.hudak So is it OK for you now or it's still not working?

Comment: It's kind of working, but the issue is, that styles are not applied to the selection.